# Create React Native App ScrollView Example Errors

Tags: macos, react-native, npm, create-react-native-app

I created CRNA app following CreateNative GetStarted steps by issuing in terminal

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

This creates app AwesomeProject and inside is `App.js` file which is the app.  I replace the content of this file with the content of the demo on how to use ScrollView that is located at http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-scrollview.html

Here is the code I copied from the link above

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ScrollView, Image, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class IScrolledDownAndWhatHappenedNextShockedMe extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scroll me plz</Text>
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>If you like</Text>
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scrolling down</Text>
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>What's the best</Text>
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Framework around?</Text>
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Image source={require('./img/favicon.png')} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:80}}>React Native</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

// skip these lines if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent(
  'AwesomeProject',
  () => IScrolledDownAndWhatHappenedNextShockedMe);
```

However, this shows error at the terminal like below and on device it shows that the module `./img/favicon.png` is unknown.  I tried adding img directory and favicon.png file in it to the root of AwesomeProject as well as inside the node_modules but the error still exists.

[image]

Please note that I just started learning about ReactNative yesterday and I am going through examples one by one but this ScrollView example is failing.  Please kindly provide clear explanation how to resolve this.

The terminal shows "`10:13:14 PM: Failed building JavaScript bundle`" as soon as CRNA app starts.

[image]

Comment: Can you possibly provide a screenshot of your file tree ( can be simplified ) aswell as provide the code you have used to import the image?

Comment: It is in the links provided and the tree is what CRNA creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `img` directory with the `favicon.png` relative to the file that specifies the requirement.

Lets assume you have a `src/index.js` with a line like `import favicon from './img/favicon.png'` or `const icon = require('./img/favicon.png')`, then your file needs to be at `src/img/favicon.png`.

Comment: Yes, I know that as stated above.  Check above, thanks

Comment: You are right but in addition to that, I needed to remove the AppRegistry line since this is CRNA

Answer (score 1):

> Just Try this if it worked then you don't have img folder where the
>   image name of favicon.png. if it works then change this image url to
>   local image url. That should works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Image, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class IScrolledDownAndWhatHappenedNextShockedMe extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scroll me plz</Text>
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>If you like</Text>
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scrolling down</Text>
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>What's the best</Text>
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Framework around?</Text>
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Image source={'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/763061332702736385/KoK6gHzp.jpg'} />
          <Text style={{fontSize:80}}>React Native</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try what you suggested but I know img dir and image is missing.  As stated above I tried adding these.  Check above.  Will definitely try your suggestion later though, thanks

Comment: That works only if I add style to source prop like <Image source={pic}  style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>, thanks.  But that does not answer my question, why it is not working if  I add img/favicon.png to the root of AwesomeProject

Comment: because you don't have img folder and with favicon.png image.